# how to send firebase push notification to all users using message api

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

in postman i have used below code to send push notification and getting error:

```
{
"notification": {
    "title": "BISMILLAH",
    "body": "TEST"
},
"to": "/Refreshed token"
}

error: {
"multicast_id": 6066192261933960650,
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [{
    "error": "InvalidRegistration"
}]
}
```

Comment: can you please review my code from below site. https://pastebin.com/eLGnwM30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ajax.

```
INSERT INTO `allcardticketingdb`.`ticket_dtl_comment`
(`comment`,
`comment_date`,
`UserID`,
`detailID`)
VALUES
(vcomment,vdate,vuser,v_ID);
END;
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to android app and coding.  I have developed webapp and fire base push notification using some tutorials. Web app is working fine and getting push notification when we send from firebase console.                          now i am trying to send notification to all users with firebase message API option. Just i need to how to send notification all registered user.  I can share you if you need my code, So that you can see and help me.